# Where can I download some default ubuntu icons

Tags: gnome, icons

I am writing a software in Java (javafx) for Ubuntu/Linux and I need some icons (such as does in gedit for example, the save icon,the search icon...) where can I find a set of such icons?

Comment: http://famfamfam.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a lot of icons on your system. A directory like `/usr/share/unity/icons/` has a lot of them dedicated to Unity. So has `/usr/share/icons/` (that one also has specific icons for gEdit per theme installed). Be careful: icons can be copyrighted so don't just copy them into your own software. Or they are "free-to-use if credits given to the author". It might be better to create your own if you want to avoid that.

There are 3 main locations on the web for icons (not specifically for gEdit; you tend to get sets of icons with a matching theme). I listed some examples from both sites. These icon sets also can have copyright.

- Deviant Art. [Captiva icon](http://bokehlicia.deviantart.com/art/Captiva-Icon-Theme-479302805) (PPA below the image).

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:captiva/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install captiva-icon-theme
```

- Gnome looks. [Square Beam](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Square-Beam?content=165094) (no PPA). [Compass](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Compass?content=160629) (PPA below the images).

[image]

[image]

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nitrux/nitrux-artwork
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compass-icon-theme
```

- [Ubuntu art.org](http://ubuntu-art.org/index.php?xcontentmode=8125). [Vibrancy](http://ubuntu-art.org/content/show.php/Vibrancy+Colors?content=167773)

[image]

---

The [Ravefinity PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ravefinity-project/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has TONS of them. [Source files](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/55d5hi5kpkzxj/HostedThemes).

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu utopic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu utopic main
```

Signing key: `1024R/E2D0EBE9`
Fingerprint: `AB3C11871E5ADDD637F8BAA89B0BBF00E2D0EBE9`

---

Going a little bit off topic: icons do not need to be Ubuntu specific to be used in Ubuntu.

Flaticon has a lot of [Vector icons](http://www.flaticon.com/) and in categories but not specific to computers but all for free. [Networking](http://www.flaticon.com/categories/networking/), [Multimedia](http://www.flaticon.com/categories/multimedia/).

---

And to close this of a [generic search on color icon sets on google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=monochrome%20icon%20set&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&gws_rd=cr&ei=j0OoVIHfOImuU8i4g9gD#tbm=isch&q=color%20icon%20set).

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the [Noobslab themes and icons page](http://www.noobslab.com/p/themes-icons.html) for a list of themes and icons for Ubuntu.

Some of the good ones include -

[Numix Circle](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme-circle)

[image]

[Moka](http://hewittsamuel.deviantart.com/art/Moka-Icon-Theme-385850133)

[image]

[Faenza](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228)

[image]

[Uniform](http://0rax0.deviantart.com/art/Uniform-Icon-Theme-453054609)

[image]

[Nitrux](http://deviantn7k1.deviantart.com/art/Nitrux-293634207)

[image]

Comment: adding images always gets upvotes :-)